# Laravel 5 Datatables Error search mb_strtolower()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, datatable

Установил пакет [yajra/laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)
При поиске возникает ошибка ErrorException in Str.php line 169: mb_strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

```
$data = Record::with('busines')->where('show', '=', 1)->get(); 
return Datatables::of($data)->make(true)

var table = $('#database-table').DataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": 'loading',
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "className":      'details-control',
                            "orderable":      false,
                            "data":           null,
                            "defaultContent": '',
                            "width": "25px",
                        },
                        {"data": 'title', name: 'title', "width": "100px"},
                        {"data": 'busines[].name', "orderable": false, "searchable":true, name: 'busines', "width": "250px"},
                        {"data": 'location', name: 'location', "width": "150px"}

                    ],


                });

                $('select#busines').on('change', function() {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                    table.columns(2).search(val).draw();
                } );`
```

Использую связь многие ко многим. 
Таблици:
records, busines, busines_records (id, busines_id, record_id). В `<select>` хранятся данные из таблици busines.

Comment: dd($data); показывает что запрос прошел? попробуйте проверить. может написать ->where('show',  1) ...

Comment: Изначально таблица загружается. Когда делаю поиск возникаеи ошибка. Смотрю в лог ошибок ругается на mb_strtolower().

Comment: Я, если чесно, не использовал с ларавел datatable, так что разобратся не могу так сразу. Меня только єта запись смущает "data": 'busines[].name' может в ней проблема?

Comment: data": 'busines[].name' - выводит записи из связаной таблици. Врядли оно влияет, но попробую убрать.